# List of lists into table (Row, Column)

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, dictionary, enumeration

I have inspiration with loop pattern diamond. The pattern diamond is replaced with the list of the lists like this code. Actually, I already print **the actual result** is not looked to row and column. the expected result is looked similar to the actual result. Dummy Coords (dum_coords) is represented the data will put into a table (row, column).

How to rule to change value None or value inside the list the value less than 3. I can replace the value to a new list. Which one better-using value or index of the list.

Please I need advice and suggestions

python, pattern diamond, list of lists

```py
l = 4

dum_coords = [None, [[1,2,3],6,7,8], [9,[1,2,3],11,12], [[1,2,3],14,15,16]]
for i in range(l):
   print("row:{}, {}".format(i, dumy_coords[i]))
```

actual result:

```py
row:0>> [None]
row:1>> [[1,2,3],6,7,8]
row:2>> [9,[1,2,3],11,12]
row:3>> [[1,2,3],14,15,16]
```

expected result:

```py
row:0>> [[None],[None],[None],[None]]
row:1>> [[None],[1,2,3],6,7]
row:2>> [9,[1,2,3],11,[1,2,3]]
row:3>> [[1,2,3],14,15,0]
```

**Updated Question**:

@Shishir Naresha suggestion me his code. for the result is similar to the expected result. But, need more than it. I can replace the value None or not None.

this my code and added with @Shishir Naresha's code

```py
dum_fish_space = [None]*5
dum_fish_pop = [None]*3
dum_fish_preying = [{"current":random.uniform(0,1)*2}]
dum_fish_following = [{"current":random.uniform(0,1)*1,"target":random.uniform(0,1)}]
dum_fish_swarming = [{"current":random.uniform(0,1)}]
dum_fish_randoming = [{"current":random.uniform(0,1)*3}]
dum_fish_battle = []

idxrange = []
new_idxrange = []

for i in range(len(dum_fish_pop)):
  temp = random.randrange(len(dum_fish_space))
  idxrange.append(random.randrange(len(dum_fish_space)))

  if temp is not idxrange:
    new_idxrange.append(temp)

l = 4

dumy_coords = [None, [[1, 2, 3], 6, 7], [9, [1, 2, 3], 11, 12], [[1, 2, 3], 14, 15, 16]]
  for i in range(l):

    if dumy_coords[i] is None:
      print("row:{}, {}".format(i, [None] * l))
    else:
      if len(dumy_coords[i]) < l:
        dif = l - len(dumy_coords[i])
        print("row:{}, {}".format(i, [None] * dif + dumy_coords[i]))
      else:
        print("row:{}, {}".format(i, dumy_coords[i]))
```

I thought is a value inside the table will change based on the index of list of the lists, I expected the result will be alike

**expected result before changing the value**:

```py
row:0>> [[None],[None],[None],[None]]
row:1>> [[None],[1,2,3],6,7]
row:2>> [9,[1,2,3],11,[1,2,3]]
row:3>> [[1,2,3],14,15,0]
```

**expected result after change the value**:

```py
row:0>> [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[None],[None]]
row:1>> [[None],[None],6,7]
row:2>> [9,[None],11,[1,2,3]]
row:3>> [[1,2,3],14,15,0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code. I hope this will help.

```
l = 4

dumy_coords = [None, [[1,2,3],6,7], [9,[1,2,3],11,12], [[1,2,3],14,15,16]]
for i in range(l):

    if dumy_coords[i] is None:
         print("row:{}, {}".format(i, [None]*l))
    else:
        if len(dumy_coords[i]) < l:
            dif = l-len(dumy_coords[i])
            print("row:{}, {}".format(i, [None]*dif+dumy_coords[i]))
        else:
            print("row:{}, {}".format(i, dumy_coords[i]))
```

Output will be as shown below:

```
row:0, [None, None, None, None]
row:1, [None, [1, 2, 3], 6, 7]
row:2, [9, [1, 2, 3], 11, 12]
row:3, [[1, 2, 3], 14, 15, 16]
```

Comment: I have another question after trying your code, how I can replace the value? even is None or another value

Comment: Your code is given the expected result, but only the half answer, please how to change the value inside the based on inside the row @shishir Naresh